# Define Object type with variable properties name in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm struggling with a React + TypeScript "problem": it actually don't stop my app, but now I've this doubt I want to remove!.. It's more of a question!

What I would like to achieve is to define the properties name of an object, whereas the properties name are given by variables. Let me explain with an example -> https://codepen.io/Gesma94/pen/xmwMzY

```
/* The 'data' property is "dynamic": it will always have this structure,
 * but the name properties (and the values) may change.
 * The 'mapping' property is used to know the name properties inside 'data'.
 */  
const series = {
  data: [
    {map1: "People reached", map2: 200},
    {map1: "People who called", map2: 117},
    {map1: "Contract signed", map2: 77}
  ],
  mapping: {
    stage: "map1",
    values: "map2"
  }
};

/* This is the actual app. */
const myPar = document.getElementById("myPar");
const { stage: stageLabel, values: valuesLabel} = series.mapping;

series.data.forEach((sample: any, index: number) => {
  myPar.innerHTML = myPar.innerHTML + "<br>" + sample[stageLabel];
});
```

As you can see, in the `forEach` I write `sample: any`.

Now, I know `sample` has a `string` (the first one will always be a `string`) property which name is `map1`, and that's because I retrieved and saved in `stageLabel`. I also know that the other property is a `number` (it's always a `number`) and its name `map2` is saved in `valueLabel`.

Now, what I'm starving to understand is how to not write `sample: any`, but define the type of `sample` using the information I retrieved earlier.
Basically, I would like to write something like: `sample: {stageLabel: string, valueLabel: number}`, but doing this way TypeScript believe `sample` has the properties `stageLabel` and `valueLabel`, since we are in "compile time" and it can't even evaluate the variables.

So, since TypeScript can't know what's inside the variables, I know I can't actually obtain `sample: {map1: string, map2: number}`, but maybe I can obtain some sort of aliasing.
For example, I write `sample: {stageLabel: string, valueLabel: number}`, and in the rest of the code I use the properties `sample.stageLabel` and `sample.valueLabel`. Then, when the application is running, those property name are evaluated, so `sample.stageLabel` is actually `sample.map1`.

I hope I've been clear enough to understand my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not actually map your data?

```js
const series = {
  data: [
    {map1: "People reached", map2: 200},
    {map1: "People who called", map2: 117},
    {map1: "Contract signed", map2: 77}
  ],
  mapping: {
    stage: "map1",
    values: "map2"
  }
};    

const myPar = document.getElementById("myPar");

let mappedData = getMappedData(series.data, series.mapping);

// append results
mappedData.forEach((record:{stage:string, value:number}) => {
  myPar.innerHTML = myPar.innerHTML + `<br>${record.stage}: ${record.value}`;
});


function getMappedData(data, mapping): {stage:string, value:number}[] {
    let stageLabel = mapping["stage"];
    let valueLabel = mapping["values"];

    return data.map(x => {        
        return { stage: x[stageLabel], value: x[valueLabel] };
    })
}
```

```html
<p id="myPar"><b>Results:</b></p>
```

Note that the compiler already nows that items in `mappedData` have the type `{stage:string, value:number}`, so you can omit this when appending and simply write:

```
// append results
mappedData.forEach(record => {
  myPar.innerHTML = myPar.innerHTML + `<br>${record.stage}: ${record.value}`;
});
```

Comment: I guess that would work: I will have my mapped data with the TypeScript checkings, so thanks.
Still, I wonder if something like I said (some sort of aliases) is possible in TypeScript. I'll mark your answer as correct if no one can give me an answer about this.. Thanks again :)